# How to use Java to sent and read a third party javascript variables

Tags: java, javascript, web, web-scraping

I have two javascript files:

http://www.dublinbikes.ie/design/marseille/javascript/gmaps_common.js
http://www.dublinbikes.ie/design/marseille/javascript/gmaps_search_station.js

Which for http://www.dublinbikes.ie/All-Stations/Station-map# website

What I want to do is to simulate the search a station status action that on the left hand side by set variable 'value' a station number and pass it to `gmaps_common.js` for execute, then read the result from `gmaps_search_station.js` that executed variable called `html` from `LeftBlock(id)` function.

Because I need run whole process automatically several times, so please suggest me could I use Java to do this and how.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: question: why do you want to use java?

Comment: This is not [tag:data-mining] (which is data *analysis* not collection!). Retagged to [tag:web-scraping].

Comment: ah, achieve the data is the first step for my project, and then I'll need put those data into my database. Anyway, thank you for remind

Answer (score 0):

You should never try to emulate a JavaScript interpreter just to get js variables out of it - just do the same thing the script would do in your language. Java is mighty enough.

The script just gets a list of stations from http://www.dublinbikes.ie/service/carto, and then queries details from http://www.dublinbikes.ie/service/stationdetails/dublin/{number} ([example](http://www.dublinbikes.ie/service/stationdetails/dublin/25)). Java has lots of HTTP and XML libraries, it will be no problem for you to do that, too.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is really help me out this problem

Comment: Could you tell me how did you get this xml link, what tools you used? Thank you.

Comment: I first searched in the network panel for them, but couldn't find them. Yet, in the source codes you linked there were ajax requests to some urls (Crtl+F for "request.open"), so I read the variables "stationDetailsUrl" and "stationsListUrl" from the console.

Comment: hi Bergi, I had another problem, I followed your way to try to find XML files that http://www.dublinbus.ie/en/RTPI/Search-RTPI-iFrame/ website requests, but when I look at this website in the firebug, I really can't find any XML address. could you help me again please? what I want to do is the same as the previous, when I search a bus time table by type the bus route, it returns the info that I need. Thank you again